# Hiding Particular Table Rows On Filter?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am currently messing around with JS/jQuery/PHP and have coded the following:

http://cole.quinnchrzan.com/tv

I wish to utilize JS/jQuery further to hide all parents (tr) of td with colspan attribute that are not immediately proceeded by a visible row when I run a search query (which hides all rows where it does not find the search string). More simply, I wish to hide the extraneous time rows in my table when a search is performed. Currently I have my filter function set to only search table cells without a colspan attribute (ie. not a time cell). This means that all time rows will always be visible.

For the lazy, here is my search function:

```
function filter(selector, query) {
    query = $.trim(query);
    query = query.replace(/ /gi, '|');

    $(selector).children('td:not([colspan])').each(function() {
        ($(this).parent().text().search(new RegExp(query, "i")) < 0) ? $(this).parent().hide() : $(this).parent().show();
    });
}
```

Comment: would be a lot simpler, and more efficient DOM search, to just add classes to the rows and only search within appropriate class and hide other class

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td[colspan]:visible').parent().each(function() {
    if($(this).siblings().first().children('td[colspan]').length > 0) {
        $(this).toggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: works great for single results but still removes time rows for any more than one result